# Unsupported opera type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong here, I've tried so many other ways of putting it but I still get an error.

> "if sum([r]) == sum(r[c] for r in Square_1):
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'"

---

```
def main():

    Square_1 =[[[] for r in range(3)] for c in range(3)]
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            User_Input=int(input("Please Enter number :")) 
            Square_1[r][c]= User_Input

            if sum([r]) == sum(Square_1[c][c] for c in range(1)):

                if sum([r]) == sum(r[c] for r in Square_1):
                    LoShuMagic = str('is a Lo Shu Magic Square!')
            else:
                LoShuMagic = str('is not a Lo Shu Magic Square :(')

    print(Square_1)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will explain to you *why* the error occurs.

Let's say `User_Input` is 42.

On the first iteration, i.e. when `r` and `c` are zero, `sum(r[c] for r in Square_1)` tries to compute the sum of `[42, [], []]`. Python does not know what `42 + []` is supposed to be and throws a `TypeError`.

Fixing your program is beyond the scope of this question-answer format because by glancing over your code I have the strong impression that you need to read the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/).

I also strongly encourage you to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) because all I had to do to find the cause of the error was to step through the instructions step by step. You could have done the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few issues with your code. First of all, change `sum([r])` to `sum(r)`. `r` is already a list, there's no need to put it into another list as your code does. That's where the first `TypeError` occurs. Let's say `r` after getting user input looks like this `[1, 2, 3]`. In your code Python tries to compute the sum of `[[1, 2, 3]]`, i.e. `1 + 2 + 3 +[]`. You have two different types: list and integer that cannot be added to each other. Another `TypeError`, described by timgeb, is similar to the error mentioned above.

Moreover, you don't need to explicitly turn string into string like here:

```
str('is a Lo Shu Magic Square!')
```

It's already a string.